# iPad fullNameFromDevice is not retrieved while iPhone fullNameFromDevice is properly retrieved

Tags: ios, ipad, uidevice

[Sample code to get fullNameFromDevice](https://github.com/tiboll/TLLNameFromDevice/tree/27d807e00b5c061c1feca17517da55d7fc6e0c29)

I have implemented this sample category to get the **"fullNameFromDevice"** inside my application.Even this example is also not giving me fullNameFromDevice for iPad.There is not any issue to read iPhone device or iPad/iPhone simulator's name using this category.Only issue comes with iPad name.What problem can be? Suggest me the appropriate solution of this issue.

Comment: Why don't you just debug and see why the name is returned empty?

Comment: I have debug but in the case of
if (![self deviceNameContainDeviceKind])
    return nil;
It is always return nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your iPad's name doesn't fit naming patterns suggested by this category.

Look at  `-(NSString *)fullNameFromDevice`:

```
if (![self deviceNameContainDeviceKind])
    return nil;
```

Then at

```
-(BOOL)deviceNameContainDeviceKind
{
    return [self.name rangeOfString:@"iPhone"].location != NSNotFound
    || [self.name rangeOfString:@"iPod"].location != NSNotFound
    || [self.name rangeOfString:@"iPad"].location != NSNotFound;
}
```

You can see that if device's name does not contain "iPhone", "iPod" or "iPad", `fullNameFromDevice` will return nil.

Comment: yes...In this method I am not getting where the problem occurs.

Comment: Though in iPhone it is working properly then what can be issue for iPad?

Comment: Open Settings on your iPad, General -> About and look at device's name.

Comment: I have to change fullNameFromDevice method.